# why does pythons `s.encode('ascii', 'replace')` fails encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, encode

Why does using replace here:

```
s = s.encode('ascii', 'replace')
```

Give me this error?:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 6755: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Isn't the whole point of 'replace' or 'ignore' to not fail when it can't decode a byte.  *Am I not understanding this?***

(sorry I can't provide the actual string, the corpus is very large)

**In any case, how do I tell python to ignore or replace characters that aren't ascii?**

Comment: You don't need to provide the actual string, you just need to provide a string that reproduces the same problem. `'\xcb'`, for instance, does just fine. Note, however, that with Python 2.x, that's an ASCII string, not a Unicode string, which is very much relevant to your problem.

Comment: That said, `replace` and `ignore` are for UnicodeEncodeError handling, not UnicodeDecodeError handling. They're used when you're **starting** from a unicode string, and creating an ASCII one.

Comment: So if I encode a string as ascii with replace option, I may not be able to decode that string safely as ascii?  Wouldn't that by definition mean that the encode function didn't create an ascii string?

Comment: "So if I encode a string as ascii with replace option, I may not be able to decode that string safely as ascii?" -- huh? I said nothing of the sort.

Comment: ...to try to restate a bit more clearly: the problem is that if you call `encode()` with a bytestring, not a unicode string, it'll try to decode it to unicode (to get a unicode string it can then encode back to ASCII as you're asking for), but using settings other than what you want. Thus, if you **really** want to transcode a bytestring through unicode, you should be writing the code to handle both directions yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you're getting a UnicodeDecodeError, not a UnicodeEncodeError.

That's because `s.encode()` **takes a unicode string as input**, but in this case you're not giving it one; you're giving it a bytestring instead.

Thus, it's encoding the bytestring you're handing it to unicode before trying to decode it, and it's in that initial encode that the error occurs.

---

This three-way round-trip is silly, but if you really wanted to do it:

```
s_bytes = '\xcb' # standard Python 2 string, aka a Python 3 bytestring
s_unicode = s_bytes.decode('ascii', 'replace') # a unicode string now
s_ascii = s_unicode.encode('ascii', 'replace') # a bytestring again
```

Comment: I am giving it a text file's contents as input (which is a string).

Comment: A Python 2 string, right? Also what Python 3 calls a bytestring? Then this answer is precisely on-point.

Comment: @anthonybell: check `type(s)`. It will be `str`, that is: a byte string, not a unicode string. Bytestrings can be converted to unicode (using `decode`); unicode strings can be converted to bytestrings (using `encode`).

Comment: Ohh, i think I got it.  `encode` changes the internal represention of the charecters in memory then?  So if my string (a byte-string) should only have ascii charecters I have to encode to ascii and decode it back from ascii to get back a normal python string with only ascii supported charecters in it?

Comment: "Have to" is a little strong -- there are other approaches available (heck, you could just filter out any character not in the printable set), but if you want to use the encode/decode facilities (which are meant for converting to and from unicode), yes, that's the way you do it.

Comment: ...example of onesuch other approach: `import string; s=''.join(c for c in s if c in string.printable)`